# Good books for- Grunfeild and Sicilian defence

Tags: sicilian-defense, grunfeld-defense

Can you please recommend good books for- Grunfeld and Sicilian defense. Would prefer separate books for either. Specially one which contains deeper analysis and has recent games illustrated.

Comment: I might be better if you divide this into two questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many types of Sicilians so you should specify which one you intend to play,

But generally a good book is: [Starting out: The Sicilian](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857445880) by John Emms

Although there are a whole multitude of excellent books written about specific Sicilians so if you could specify more than I could recommend some excellent books on those specific Sicilians.

For Grunfeld it's a little simpler, an excellent book is [Understanding the Grunfeld](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1901983099) by Jonathan Rowson, which is a very well regarded book.

There are many more excellent Grunfeld books but far too many to mention in this post.

Answer (score 1):

Winning with the Sicilian by Mark Taimanov.

Answer (score 1):

Sicilian is not in my repertory and I want to include it.

I haven't read it yet, but after reading other books by GM De la Villa and some feedback I have read, I would recommend blindly **["Dismantling the Sicilian: A Complete Modern Repertoire for White"](https://www.amazon.es/Dismantling-Sicilian-Complete-Modern-Repertoire/dp/9056917528)**.